# How to test a local bot?

Tags: localhost, botframework, ngrok

I developed a simple bot on my machine (http://localhost:3978). I would like to embed a custom chat client in my web site using direct line API. Is there a way I can test this without deploying my bot to an Azure website ? I would like to be able to debug on my local machine (without having to do Azure remote debugging...).

I tried to register my bot with a localhost endpoint (http without basic auth and https) but it did not work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to test my Bot application in Microsoft Teams or Skype after registering in bot dir but without publishing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374610/is-it-possible-to-test-my-bot-application-in-microsoft-teams-or-skype-after-regi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one of the possible solution is to use ngrok that creates a "fake" https endpoint forwarding to your local machine

https://ngrok.com/

I tested it successfully with facebook messenger platform on a windows laptop

Answer (score 1):

We have a tool that we built for just this purpose: http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/commands/proxy/

Requests and responses from the BOT Framework will be sent directly to your machine. We built this originally to assist with Alexa skill development, but it is also useful here.

We also have wrappers for AWS Lambdas in Node.js and Python. This allows you to just write Lambda code and not worry about making them available as an HTTP service.

Our Github projects are here:
https://github.com/bespoken/bst
https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy

Answer (score 0):

To test your BOT, you might want to consider using the Bot Framework Emulator. [Here](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#use-the-bot-framework-emulator-to-test-your-bot-application) is the explanation on how to use it.

Comment: I would like to develop custom behaviors such as embedding html form within my chat so bot emulator does not help here...

Answer (score 0):

Configure Web Chat channel which provides a HTML template (iframe), which you can then embed in your HTML document.

Answer (score -3):

by using the ngrock it create a fake url that redirect to your machine.

Comment: This is just a poorly worded repetition of an existing answer.