# Is it possible to test my Bot application in Microsoft Teams or Skype after registering in bot dir but without publishing it?

Tags: botframework

I have registered my bot application in MS Bot directory. I can able to communicate with my message endpoint using Bot Framework Emulator. but when I tried the same in MS teams and Skype. the bot is not responding to my message.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel to your local environment.

In a nutshell, you need to run (assuming your local bot is running on port 3979):

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 3979
```

And then update your bot endpoint in the Bot Framework portal with the url ngrok will provide you.

[image: ngrok config]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/07/masked-bot-debug-environment.png))</sub>

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jamiedalton/ms-bot-framework-ngrok) post for all the details